# TCP: When server listening on random port how does client know which port to send to?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, serversocket

The problem: In java you can create a socket on the server with ServerSocket(0) and it will choose a random port to listen on. However when you create a socket on the client to send a message with Socket(addr, port) there is no apparent way to determine which port on the server you need to send to. I couldn't find anything about this option through web searches besides the basic "if you put 0 it will chose a random port". Does anyone know or have a resource that could explain what this scenario is supposed to look like from the client end?

Some background: I am currently converting a system from UDP to TCP. The reason I need the server to listen on a random port is that my server/client do not have a strict server/client relationship. So the "server" in this situation is really an application that I need to open multiple instances of on one PC. The old way of having predetermined send/receive ports is causing only one instance to be able to open a port and all communication is being redirected to that instance. My understanding that the best way to fix this problem is for each instance to use a different port, and the best way for that is to do ServerSocket(0). Despite including this background, I do not want comments on how messed up the situation is, only answers pertaining to the problem.

Comment: If the "clients" and "servers" are on the same network, you can have the "servers" broadcast their current IPs and ports.  "Clients" can receive those broadcasts and decide which "server" to connect to. Or, setup another listener on the same PC as the "servers" and make it know the "servers" current ports, then give it a fixed listening port of its own for clients to connect to and query which "servers" are available.

Answer (score 1):

If a fixed port number is not part of the server's documented setup / protocol, then the only way for clients to figure out is to have the running/active servers publish that information in some datastore, the location and details of which are documented and known by the clients, and where that datastore is reachable for the clients.

[Or have the clients run a portscan each time they want to connect.  It will work but probably not as fast as your users would like.]

And your situation is indeed messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you are on the same IP subnet with all the servers/clients, then you could use UPnP to signal which random port new instances of your application are running on, and similarly other instances could monitor UPnP to discover this new instance.
I've never implemented UPnP in Java, but suspect libraries are out there..
eg. https://github.com/jupnp/jupnp

Comment: In particular, [Simple Service Discovery Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol), which is part of uPNP.  Or, there are other similar protocols not related to uPNP, like [Service Location Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Location_Protocol), [Zero-configuration networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking), [WS-Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery), etc.